# Creating a JApplet using netbeans and maven

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans-7, japplet

Hi so ive been trying to create a JApplet do create a GUI for a project im working on. But I cannot seem to be able to get it to work when using maven with the project. I have created the GUI visually this far, and it works fine in a non-maven setting. I require maven in order to get some packages I need to run my project...

So my question is, what steps do i need to take in order to get a working JApplet using maven?

My applet class name is ArFileJApplet and its in the package com.allcare.ArFile with the project name being ArFile.

Also I was hoping to be able to run this applet as a web service naturally...

I get the feeling that is has something to do with the .jar file i need for the applet to run, does maven generate this? and where can i find its name?

Comment: *"what steps do i need to take in order to get a working JApplet using maven?"*  First figure out how to deploy the applet using pure HTML, then adapt the [deployJava.js](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) into that.  Once you have it working with the deployment toolkit script, post that HTML and I might be able to help you adapt that to ..Maven, whatever.  *"I was hoping to be able to run this applet as a web service"* An app. launched using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) will be easier & better..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have got it working using only pure HTML, the problem is I want it to use apache Maven to grab libraries that i need during runtime, it works fine with HTML, here is a link to the tutorial i followed and built upon if that helps...
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html

Comment: nevermind, i simply changed over to using an ant script to grab the libraries for me, works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to use an ANT script instead, this worked much better for grabbing libraries and gave me no troubles.

Comment: So my fried, how did you do that? Using ant. 
I am facing the same situation here, needing some jars in my applet project but not able to do it with Maven.
How did you manage to do that using Ant?